# Event issues with bootstrap in iOS

Tags: jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, cordova

im using **bootstrap 3.2** with **jQuery 2.1.1** and **jQuery mobile custom v1.4.3** (only events) with **Cordova 3.4** for creating an app.

I bind a taphold event on a div and show a bootstrap modal. When i release my finger the modal closes instant. Its working in **Android** and **windows phone 8** but not **iOS 5,6,7** ...

function when taphold event fires:

```
function onTaphold(ev) {
    console.log("taphold");
    var dev = getDevice(ev.currentTarget.id);
    $("#contextMenu").attr('device-id', ev.currentTarget.id);
    $('#contextMenu').modal('show');
}
```

Comment: Give us some Code, and tell us exactly what you want the taphold event/the bootstrap modal to do. Should it close or should it not?

Comment: i want to show the modal when the taphold fires (it works) but when the modal is shown with the .modal-backdrop div and i put my finger up it closes immediately in iOS

Comment: Did you try to disable the touch callout?

Comment: i tried to unbind the click and tap event on the backdrop div without success